# VsCode: escape widnows path in launch.json command

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmake, gdb, openocd

I'm using Vscode + CMake + arm-none-eabi + openocd to develop in linux.
I've trouble migrating this setup to windows. this is the relevant snippet:

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
    ...
      "setupCommands": [
      ...
        { "text": "-file-exec-and-symbols ${command:cmake.launchTargetPath}", "description": "load file", "ignoreFailures": false},
      ...
      ],
    ...
    }
  ...
  ]
}
```

`${command:cmake.launchTargetPath}` returns a windows path with `'\'` delimiter that is interpreted as an escape char when passed as a gdb argument.

`"C:\\some\path\output.elf"` is passed as `"C:\somepathoutput.elf"`

Comment: things are still being sorted/figured out in maintainer land https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/9785. I'll write up an answer post when there's more clarity on what exactly the problem is and which resolution proposal will be taken.

Comment: Will wait for your answer

Answer (score 0):

- Install [Command Variable Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable)
- Define an input with the transform command to convert backslashes into slashes.
- Use the transformed input instead of the original command

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "text": "-file-exec-and-symbols ${command:cmake.launchTargetPath}",
                    "description": "load file",
                    "ignoreFailures": false
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "inputs": [
        {
            "id": "launchTargetPath",
            "type": "command",
            "command": "extension.commandvariable.transform",
            "args": {
                "text": "${command:cmake.launchTargetPath}",
                "find": "\\\\",
                "replace": "/",
                "flags": "g"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```